# How Do I implement voice recognition to launch application?

Tags: android, service, listener, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm a noob to android development and I am trying to figure out a way to launch my application using voice recognition.  I want to  begin a RecognitionService that runs in the background after a user has signed in for the first time.  I want to service to run continually and allow the user to launch the app using a key word. I will allow the user to stop the service in a settings activity.  Currently, I am able to start the service and keeping it running in the background but I haven't been able to figure how  to call the onStartListening method in the RecognitionService.  Any help solving this is greatly appreciated.

My Code

```
 public class VoiceRecognitionService extends RecognitionService {

private SpeechRecognizer m_EngineSR;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("SimpleVoiceService", "Service started");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("SimpleVoiceService", "Service stopped");
}

@Override
protected void onCancel(Callback listener) {
    m_EngineSR.cancel();
}

@Override
protected void onStartListening(Intent recognizerIntent, Callback listener) { //<--How Do I call this method?
    m_EngineSR.setRecognitionListener(new VoiceResultsListener(listener));
    m_EngineSR.startListening(recognizerIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onStopListening(Callback listener) {
    m_EngineSR.stopListening();
}


/**
 *
 */
private class VoiceResultsListener implements RecognitionListener {

    private Callback m_UserSpecifiedListener;

    /**
     *
     * @param userSpecifiedListener
     */
    public VoiceResultsListener(Callback userSpecifiedListener) {
        m_UserSpecifiedListener = userSpecifiedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        try {
            m_UserSpecifiedListener.beginningOfSpeech();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            m_UserSpecifiedListener.bufferReceived(buffer);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        try {
            m_UserSpecifiedListener.endOfSpeech();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        try {
            m_UserSpecifiedListener.error(error);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) { ; }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        try {
            m_UserSpecifiedListener.partialResults(partialResults);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        try {
            m_UserSpecifiedListener.readyForSpeech(params);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        try {
            m_UserSpecifiedListener.results(results);
            Log.e("SimpleVoiceService Results:", "Service stopped");

            ArrayList<String> result = results.getStringArrayList("results_recognition");

            Log.e("SimpleVoiceService Results:", result.get(0));
            if (result.isEmpty() == false) {
                for (int i = 0; i<(result.size()-1);i++) {
                    if(result.get(i).equals("shoot back")||result.get(i).equals("Launch App")){
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.bmoney.testapp.MAIN_ACTIVITY");
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }



        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        try {
            m_UserSpecifiedListener.rmsChanged(rmsdB);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Manifest

```
  <service android:name="com.bmoney.testapp.VoiceRecognitionService" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I hadn't had the chance to test this out, I think the answer lies in [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/the-fastest-route-between-voice-search.html) android developers blog post.
This implementation though uses the "Ok Google" (I don't know if this bothers you).

In short you have to implement a [seachable activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html?utm_campaign=voice-search-1014&utm_source=gdbc&utm_medium=blog&utm_source=gdbc&utm_medium=blog#DeclaringSearchableActivity) and add this in your AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchableActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I have triple-checked everything, but just can't get this search query delivered to my app. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Well... looks like the app needs to be published on Play Store:
https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/afSRdDQiy1N - look for comments by Jarek Wilkiewicz. Going to try this next.